# Compute transformation between points given in two coordinate frames

Tags: opencv, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have two world coordinate systems, such as `coorA`, `coorB`. Each system has 4 points (3D points with xyz), and both in right-hand coordinate system.

I have tried it with `cv::svd`, but the result wasn't right. I want to calculate the rotation and translation matrix from `coorA` to `coorB`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Your system is over-defined, therefore you should use a method that minimizes an error measure. A good solution is Umeyama's method.

Judging from your tags, you prefer a solution within OpenCV, but there you would need to implement such method yourself.
You seem to be using C++, the easiest solution is probably to use the Eigen math header libraries and its function [Eigen::umeyama](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#gab3f5a82a24490b936f8694cf8fef8e60).
OpenCV can do [data conversions to Eigen](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/daf/group__core__eigen.html).

Comment: ,you are right,the system is  over-defined.The two coordinate system was in same frame,so i merge the 2 system and there is no need to transform them.Thank you!